# JQuery: .val('') leaves line break in textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm working on an AJAX chat room. My problem is that right now when I press enter, there's occasionally left an empty line break in the textarea. So far I've attempted to remove it with .val(''), .text(''), .html('') and .empty(), but none of them have worked. The preventDefault() command seems to get triggered, because I don't constantly get this error but when it does occur, it keeps getting fired. So far I haven't even figured out what causes the change. Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code. I'm catching the key events with,

```
$("textarea[name='input']").keydown(function(event) {
    key = event.which;

    if(key == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        submitInput();
        }
    });
```

then send handle the input with AJAX with

```
function submitInput() {
    activeRoom = $(".tabs .active span").text(); 
    message = $("textarea[name='input']").val();

    message = message.trim();

    if(message != "") {
        if(message.charAt(0) == "/") {
            // Catch slash commands
            }
        else {
            $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/message_send.php",
            data: { nickname: nickname, room_name: activeRoom, message : message },
            async: false
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                getMessages(activeRoom);

                clearInput();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The function that is not working correctly is currently looking like this. It's very simple, partly because I have no idea what to add to it to make it work. I've had my console log show me the order in which functions are fired and finished and this is either last or coming straight after getMessages(). It's supposed to work... isn't it?

```
function clearInput() {
    // Empty input
    $("textarea[name='input']").val('');

    // Put input in focus
    $("textarea[name='input']").focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

message = message.replace(/^(\n)/,'');

Comment: I ran that as: 

 textarea = $("textarea[name='input']");
 textarea.val('');
 textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/^(\n)/,''));


No effect.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. The keydown event fires multiple times if you press enter for too long. Changed the event to keypress and everything works just fine.